# Change the default names of foreign keys in one-to-many mapping : HIBERNATE

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a one-to-many mapping, which maps a user(UserDetails) to an ArrayList of Vehicles. I want to know whether it is possible to override the default foreign key name which references the id of table vehicle (vehicleid) in user_details_vehicle

```
@OneToMany
@ForeignKey(name="FK_USER_DETAILS")
@JoinTable(name="user_details_vehicles",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="vehicle_id")
    }
)
public Collection<Vehicle> getVehicles() {
  return vehicles;
}
```

The create statement that I would like at the end is :

```
CREATE TABLE user_details_vehicles (
 user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 vehicle_id int(11) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY vehicle_id (vehicle_id),
 KEY FK_USER_DETAILS (user_id),
 KEY FK_VEHICLE (vehicle_id),
 CONSTRAINT FK_VEHICLE FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_id) REFERENCES vehicle (vehicleId),
 CONSTRAINT FK_USER_DETAILS FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user_details (user_id)
)
```

This is just for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already use `ForeignKey.name`.  Set `ForeignKey.inverseName` to name the other FK.

Answer (score 0):

yes just change it in the

inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="vehicle_id")

if you want it as my_vehicle_id

```
then set inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="my_vehicle_id")
```

Comment: Thanks but I was talking about the foreign keys generated by default. Example Hibernate generates the key FKE74E2618AF42C7A1 for the foreign key. I want to override the default name to be more meaningful.

Comment: That doesnt sound right, if hibernate is creating the tables, the columns are named acording to your mapping, but you're telling me that hibernate made a FKE74E2618AF42C7A1 column by default?

Comment: No sir i was talking about the name of the foreign key not columns.